# How to access reversed relationship using Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here are my models :

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=PROTECT)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plans, on_delete=PROTECT)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    activation_token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/thumb/', null=True, blank=True)
    renew_data = models.DateField()
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And as you see the Profile model have `user` field that is related to the `Abstract user` of django framework. now here is how i call them using an API :

**Serializers**

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['company_name']


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile_set = ProfileSerializer(
        read_only=True, many=True)  # many=True is required

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = ['username', 'id', 'profile_set']
```

But when I call the `API` it shows only the fields `username` and `'id` but not the `profile_set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserSerializer` should like this,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # no need to set `profile.all` as you have related name profile defined in your model
    profile_set = ProfileSerializer(source='profile', many=True)   

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = ['username', 'id', 'profile_set']
```

OR,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=True) # as you have related name `profile`  

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = ['username', 'id', 'profile']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the source of your serializer:

```py
profile_set = ProfileSerializer(
    source='profile.all',
    read_only=True, many=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've set the `related_name` on your foreign key:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=PROTECT)
```

This defines the reverse relation name, so that's how you need to refer to it in DRF, too:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    depth = 1
    fields = ['username', 'id', 'profile']
```

Since it's clearly a plural, I'd also suggest you rename `profile` to `profiles`.